# UIImageView Using to much memory while caching images

Tags: swift

In my app I retrieve allot of images from our server, so I decide to create my own cache system, (I prefer my own, because in this way I can fully understand it and modify it).

Every image I download I save it on RAM `NSCache` and disk `NSTemporaryDirectory`. When I load the image if I have it on RAM i return the `UIImage` but for some reason I'm consuming tons of RAM, even I'm using the image I have on my `NSCache`

I really don't know why or how to solve it, or if is a normal behaviour?

I already try to remove the unused images from NSCache and the RAM stays the same. I try it on iPhone 6 and RAM goes from 40MB when it starts to 100MB after scrolling and loading over 30-40 photos. If I continue scrolling in those 30-40 photos (not loading new ones) the RAM goes up to 200MB

I leave my code, I hope someone can said me if I'm doing it ok or no

Also it gets streamy slow loading the images from disk, when I scroll really fast throw the 40 photos. I think its loading each photo then release it and loading the new one, but how can I solve this also?

```
import UIKit

let _sharedCache: EDCacheImages = { EDCacheImages() }()

class EDCacheImages: NSObject {

    var cachedImages = NSCache()

    class func sharedCache() -> EDCacheImages {
        return _sharedCache
    }

    //Get image async form URL
    //In this function we will check if we have cached the image or we need to download it
    //Call back with image, if callback doesn't exist, image will cache on RAM and Disk
    func getImageFromURL(url: NSURL, withCompletionHandler completionHandler:((image: UIImage) -> Void)? = nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

            //Check if cached images exist
            if let image = self.getCacheImageForName(url.absoluteString!) {

                //Image exist
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if let completion = completionHandler {
                        completion(image: image)
                    }
                }


            }else{
                //Image doesn't existe we need to download it
                if let image = self.asyncDownloadImageFromURL(url) {
                    //Image successfully downloaded
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        if let completion = completionHandler {
                            completion(image: image)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func asyncDownloadImageFromURL(url: NSURL) -> UIImage? {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
                //We cache the image in RAM nad Disk
                cacheImage(img, withName: url.absoluteString!)
                return img
            }
        }

        return nil
    }


    // MARK: Cache images
    private func cacheImage(image:UIImage, withName name:String) {
        cacheImageOnRAM(image, withName: name)
        cacheImageOnDisk(image, withName: name)
    }

    private func cacheImageOnRAM(image:UIImage, withName name:String) {
        //Cache image on RAM
        println("saving cached image \(name.md5)")
        cachedImages.setObject(image, forKey: name.md5)
    }

    private func cacheImageOnDisk(image:UIImage, withName name:String) {
        //Cache image on disk
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(name.md5).png"
        fileManager.createFileAtPath(path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Get cached images
    private func getCacheImageForName(name:String) -> UIImage? {
        //Check if image is cached on RAM
        if let img = cachedImages.objectForKey(name.md5) as? UIImage {
            println("getting cached image \(name.md5)")
            return img
        }

        //Check if is cached in DISK
        let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(name.md5).png"
        if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {
            //Cache image on RAM
            cacheImageOnRAM(img, withName: name)
            return img
        }

        return nil
    }

    // MARK: Remove Cached Images
    func removeCacheImageOnRamForName(name: String) {
//        cachedImages.removeObjectForKey(name.md5)
    }

}
```

On my UIImageView I create this code to clean

```
func cleanImageViewWithURL(url: NSURL, cleanCache: Bool = true) {
        self.image = nil
        EDCacheImages.sharedCache().removeCacheImageOnRamForName(url.absoluteString!)
    }
```

Comment: Hopefully this is just in your sample code, but the body of your `removeCacheImageOnRamForName(_:)` method is commented out.  Also, [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) has most of this built in, and it's a nice, well-tested CocoaPod.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLynch, thanks, this is a test code I'm doing, I forgot the commented part I was testing. And I'm creating my own so I can learn how to accomplish this and not only implement a bunch of plugins